# Returning a file in a new browser window using mvc 3 razor vb.net

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

I have a function that returns a generated PDF file but the problem is it shows it in the current browser window... I need for it to open in a new window. I dont see how I can pass it into a view for displaying where I could simply use target: _blank. Any Ideas?

```
     Function showUserPDF(ByVal pdfName As String) As ActionResult
        Dim _fileName As String = pdfName
        Dim _path As String = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory) + "\PDF_Files\"
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + _fileName + ";")

        Return File(_path + _fileName, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf, _fileName)

    End Function
```

Comment: Just open the action in a new window?

Comment: I guess I could say something line Return View() on it but inside the new window how would I display the pdf file???

Comment: Just open the action in a new window. :) Don't change the action method, just make sure the action is requested in a new window. If this is a link, just add target=whatever to the link.

Comment: hmmmmm i never have been successful with passing variables into view.. Which is what I would have to do here since the pdf filename changes .

Comment: [Hey, check this out.](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc3-part1-cs)

Comment: good stuff. Been over that tut numerous times over the past 6 months...

Comment: Update this does not work I have the following code on the calling action link:  @Html.ActionLink("Print Name Tag", "PrintID", New With {.target = "_blank", .id = currentitem.id}) and no new window opens..

Comment: The above does not work because mvc needs a `Nothing` in the route parameters spot which is what I am specifying my target = "_blank" and id in... Adding a `Nothing,` before that would take care of my issue with it not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't control the window from server-side code - you need to launch the original request targetting a new window, eg.:

```
Html.ActionLink("Text", "Action", null, new { target="_blank" })
```

If the request comes from a redirect, then the original request before the redirect would need to be opened in the new window.

You could also use [`Content-Disposition: attachment`](http://www.jtricks.com/bits/content_disposition.html) header to force the browser to prompt to download.